# String check: fixed and variable part

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7, python-3.x

Given this line:

```
[4] Item status: FAILED
```

I would like to use the most efficient and maintainable way (possibly with regular expressions) to check if this line is "correct". Here, the correctness means that

1. the square brackets and text `"Item status: "` are always there
2. a number is between the square brackets
3. status reported after `:` could be in `["PASSED", "FAILED", "NOT EXECUTED"]`

I'm looking for a way to somehow inject a variable into a regular expression, to account for the point 3.

Answer (score 3):

Rather than *"inject a variable"*, I think you want to use the `|` ("or") option:

```
regex = re.compile(r"""
    \[\d+\]\s+                      # a number in square brackets
    Item\ status:\s+                # followed by Item status:
    (?:FAILED|PASSED|NOT EXECUTED)  # then one of these three options
    $                               # and nothing further
""", re.VERBOSE)
```

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/gQ6pW4/2

If the list could be variable, you could use `str.format` to insert `'|'.join(options)` into the appropriate group.

Comment: Might add a `"$"` at the end so that nothing else can come after the status (and the status can not be, e.g. "PASSED NOT" or something).